# Add input from user inmidatley to <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For this example i have a simple html markup:

```
<input id="INPUT"/>
```

What i would like to achieve now is that when the user types something. His input is inmidiatley shown in the `#INPUT`. I tried this, but somehow it wont work:

```
$('document').keydown( function(e) {
   $('#INPUT').focus();
});
```

What should i do instead? Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/GdVvd/

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @java_user OP is asking how he can design a page where on any key press on the page will make the focus go over to the input. Just like Google search page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need quotes around `document`, as the selector will look for element having a `tagName` matching "document" if you put it in quotes.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdVvd/2/)**

```
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
   $('#INPUT').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A HTML5 solution would be to simply give your `input` element an `autofocus` attribute. This will make it focused when the page loads:

```
<input id="input" autofocus />
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GdVvd/3/).

Note however that this solution currently does not work on IE or Firefox.

Comment: @prash interesting, seems Firefox doesn't support the `autofocus` attribute. This works fine in Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove single quote from document try below:

```
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
   $('#INPUT').focus();
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GdVvd/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You should remove quote:

```
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
   $('#INPUT').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the '' from document like so.

```
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
   $('#INPUT').focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GdVvd/

Answer (score 0):

Your js function will work as other users pointed out if you remove the `single quotes` around   `document`.
This also implies that any key users presses will make the textbox on focus. Instead you can further try to check for valid keys that you want to allow to users.

```
//var keycodes = [];
$(document).keydown( function(e) {
   if(e.which == 'somekeycode')
     $('#INPUT').focus();
});
```